# evaluateFormulaCellEnum(cell) is failing to understand the formula in excel using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to parse an excel file which contains formula cells.I am using FormulaEvaluator API of POI.It can parse most of the cells of that excel but some of the cell i am getting a different format of formula from the earlier one and there it is failing . The formula which is correctly evaluating is

```
=IF('TreeData-Report'!AB172="H";"";SUM('TreeData-Report'!C172:'TreeData-Report'!E172))
```

And the formula evaluation code that i am using is

```
public String evalFormulaCell(Cell cell) {
    String cellValue = "";
    switch (formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellEnum(cell)) {
    case BOOLEAN:
        cellValue = String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
    case NUMERIC:
        cellValue = formatDoubleNumberToString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        break;
    case STRING:
        cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;
    case BLANK:
        cellValue = "";
        break;
    case ERROR:
        cellValue = String.valueOf(cell.getErrorCellValue());
        break;
    case _NONE:
        cellValue = "";
        break;
    // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never occur
    case FORMULA:
        cellValue = "";
        break;
    }
    return cellValue;
}
```

This is the formula which it can not parse

```
='Calc-Report'!AD3
```

I am not understanding why it can not evalute this formula , it is getting the below exception also ,

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected arg eval type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(OperandResolver.java:231)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:30)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:36)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:523)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:290)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:723)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
```

Please help i don't have any clue of this . Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if not the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: It's 3.16......

Comment: 3.17 has been out for 7 months now...

Comment: @Gagravarr the version i can not change

Comment: `Unexpected arg eval type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval)`: A formula in the evaluation chain is missing an argument. But this cannot be `='Calc-Report'!AD3`. Maybe sheet "Calc-Report" in cell `AD3` contains also a formula and this formula is missing an argument? For example `=ROUND(21/7;)` will be evaluated in `Excel` as  `=ROUND(21/7;0)`. But this is `Excel`'s tolerance. `apache poi` insists on the second argument being present and not simply be nothing.

Comment: @AxelRichter how i can read the value of  this cell ?

Comment: I am also getting same issue. Do we have any fix for it?